# What's the difference between "git repository folder" and "existing work dir" in context of git_repository_open()?

Tags: libgit2

The [docs for git_repository_open](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/repository/git_repository_open) say:

> The 'path' argument must point to either a git repository folder, or an existing work dir.

What does "existing work dir" that mean exactly? Can any subfolder be used? A detailed explanation or example would be so helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by cmn_ in #libgit2 on freenode:

`<cmn_> shurcooL: you're right, I was thinking of git_repository_discover()
<cmn_> which *will* take any of those paths and give you the right one
<cmn_> shurcooL: what you usually call a "git repository" is two things, the gitdir and the worktree; the worktree is where you files live (and the top-level has the .git), and the gitdir is where git stores its data
<cmn_> what it's telling you is that if you have someproject/ and someproject/.git you can pass either of those paths and libgit2 will load the repository; the former being the worktree/workdir and the latter the repository`